camera view doesn't show after a few launches
I use flutter's camera plugin with google's ml kit for barcode scanning camera_view and barcodeScannerView and sometimes the camera just won't open and show the error when the controller is not initialized:
  Widget _liveFeedBody() {
    if (_cameras.isEmpty) {
      print("list of cameras empty");
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (_controller == null) {
      print("controller is null");
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (_controller?.value.isInitialized == false) {
      print("controller not initialized");
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } 

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: _changingCameraLens
                ? Center(
                    child: const Text('Changing camera lens'),
                  )
                : CameraPreview(
                    _controller!,
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: _customPainter,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          _switchLiveCameraToggle(),
          _flashToggle(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

E/flutter (24045): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference
